# Error running project with Visual Studio IISexpress error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

Here is the screenshot of what i get

[image]

I closed visual studio and open again; but got same thing.
i have shutdown my pc and try running again but got same thing.
i open past projects and try to run it, it ran without any issues, but my current project keep displaying same thing.

Comment: try answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68694790/visual-studio-2019-unable-to-connect-to-web-server-iis-express

Comment: Could you please share your launchsetting.json file? You can try changing port number there. You should try changing last digit of any given port number because, this might be causing due to using same port number. In addition, within your project root folder you would seen .vs folder you can delete that and rebuilt your project and run it. Hope that would resolve the issue.