# Unable to connect to web server - Visual Studio 2022

Tags: asp.net-core

When I run my ASP.NET Core application, Visual Studio shows a warning

> Unable to connect to web server 'MiddlewareTraining'. The web server is no longer running.

I tried to close Visual Studio 2022 again and reopen but the prompt kept coming every time I run the application

[image: Visual studio error screenshot]

Comment: If you added [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it would be easier to tell. I'm not sure, at this stage.
Have you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68694790/visual-studio-2019-unable-to-connect-to-web-server-iis-express)?

Answer (score 0):

If the project was created on another computer and you cloned it, it may be that your machine does not have the .NET runtime version installed. Try installing and running the project again.